# Stop ASP.NET postback in BeginRequestHandler?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, postback, dom-events

I am checking for a certain condition in the `BeginRequestHandler` function and want to stop post back occurring if that condition is met?

I have tried the following code:

```
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
         if ($("#searchform").is(":visible")) {
             return false;
         }
}
```

and

```
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
         if ($("#searchform").is(":visible")) {
             var objMan = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
             if (objMan.get_isInAsyncPostBack()) {
                 objMan.abortPostBack();
             }
         }
}
```

But this had no effect, is it possible to stop the post back at this point and if so how would you go about it?

Basically I do not want the page to post back to the server if the search form element is visible.

Comment: I think, once you get to the BeginRequestHandler point, the postback is already a given. Sounds like you want to look at a validation handler to verify things before the postback starts.

Comment: Hmm that's what I was thinking but hoping wasn't the case, trouble is that it is a .NET Timer that is triggering the post back so I'm not sure how I could get around it.

Comment: If the visible state of the searchform element is changed based on the other ASP web controls (i.e. the user interacts with your page and the searchform shows or hides) then you could set the timer's enabled property at the same time.